# What is this device connected to my HVAC unit?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I have this device connected to my HVAC unit in my apartment. I only have it in two of my rooms. In one of the other rooms I do not have this unit and was able to install an ecobee seamlessly. However, in the two rooms with this device I see the other color wires stuffed in the wall, but only one red and one white wire is connected to the thermostat.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be the control module for a [Bryant T6-PAC](http://www.bryant.com/bryant/en/us/products/controls-thermostats/t6-pac01-a/) thermostat. http://homeappliance.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/bryant/t6pac.htm

Comment: Can I get rid of it and use the other/color wires in the wall to hook up my ecobee?